# Can an electrical breaker panel be mounted on an interior wall?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Log home new construction. Need to bring 200 AMP service in from meter to a 200 AMP breaker panel.
Want to install panel on an interior wall - how far from point of penetration into home can the breaker panel be located?

Comment: Have you checked your local building codes for guidance?

Comment: Yes, check your local electrical codes and also your local utility's electrical service regulations.  (Some PoCos even force you to use a utility provided meter socket and/or prohibit you from putting a meter-main in!)

Answer (score 4):

### If you use a *Meter-Main*, the panel can go anywhere

You are thinking of the old paradigm, which was driven **by builders** and their desire to use the cheapest service equipment possible, since they buy in thousand quantity.  That meant a simple meter pan, a separate enclosure for breakers (and often no main breaker at all, but a Rule of Six setup where the 6 largest breakers were the "main"...) and a *totally unfused, 10,000 amp capable* cable run between them. **The vulnerability of this service cable necessitated keeping it as short as possible**, and that is the rule you are thinking of.

But since we're not doing the risky Rule of Six anymore, it begs the question: Why have the main breaker with the other breakers? Why not at the meter pan where it will protect the downline cable?

And municipalities badly want the main breaker at the meter pan, for the sake of their fire departments - that lets them* quickly de-energize the structure without having to pull the meter and leave a gaping hole with energized contacts inside. (this also renders safe microinverter-type rooftop solar).

So many cities, and now NEC 2020, now require "meter-mains".

As such, meter-mains are readily available, and solve your problem elegantly and with a bow.   Thanks to the meter-main, the cable between meter pan and breaker panel *has no restrictions* and can go anywhere.  **That means you can put your panel anywhere**. Well, not quite.

### Place it where people will keep the *Working Space* clear

NEC requires a working area around the panel that is flat (not on stairs), the width of the equipment *but at least 30" wide (doesn't need to be centered), 36" deep from the face of the box, and 78" tall so a 6'6" electrician can work.

**This space must be kept clear at ALL times**.  And the architect should be thinking hard about this, because *people gonna do what people gonna do*.  If the architect places the panel in a corner *that lends itself to being used as storage*, people WILL use it as storage.  Etc. Etc.

Therefore, the "best practice" in panel placement is to have it face a hallway or threshold that people will naturally want to keep clear. I'm sure you have hallways in your home that are clear because it would be weird to store stuff there. That's the kind of place that suits a panel.

---

---

---

---

*  Some people dislike outdoor mains because they fear vandals cutting power.  That's fine, put a lock on it - firemen expect this and will bring a [master key](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Tools-Hand-Tools-Cutting-Tools-Bolt-Cutters/N-5yc1vZc259). And anyway, vandals can already cut your power by twisting off the power company's tamper seal and pulling your meter.  That won't change.

Comment: "6 1/2 ft or the height of the equipment, whichever is greater." -- 110.26(A)(3) which apparently didn't exist when my house was built.  Oops.

Comment: @Robert I try to aim for relevant brevity.  I've never seen residential equipment more than 6'6" tall.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's that tall, but mounted so high the top is nearly 8' above the floor and doesn't have the 30x36 clearances at that "height".

Answer (score 1):

The location of the meter is usually determined by the power company and most local codes require a main breaker by the meter. After that, it's pretty much up to the builder where the circuit breaker panel goes. Interior walls are fine, most panels are installed on them. Distance wise from the outside disconnect, no minimum or maximum. I've seen and installed them on the other side of the house, running through attics. Keep in mind that those will be large cables you'll be running so the shorter the distance, the cheaper the run. Think aluminum wires.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others here that a meter / main outside is a good idea and is being required in more and more places depending upon what version of the NEC the local AHJ has adopted.

There are limits on how far you can place the main panel from the meter since the are essentially not protected from over-current (yeah there are fuses on the PoCo transformer, but that transformer could be serving multiple houses and from a practical perspective don't provide virtually any overcurrent protection for a single service).  But once you have an external breaker, the main wires/cables inside the home are protected and not subject to the distance rules.

I'd think about the length of branch circuits needed and place the main panel in a NEC acceptable location that is aesthetically acceptable (following all the requirements that Harper mentioned in his answer, of course).  Situating the panel centrally may cost some more on the main run wires/cables, but may save money on branch circuits, esp. given the price of copper cables, especially EXPENSIVE IS  6/3 (for a range, if electric, 10/3 for water heaters if electric as well as for clothes dryer, that stuff is EXPENSIVE right now, did I say EXPENSIVE twice? There's a reason for that. And 12/2 and 14/2 is also very expensive.   I know pricing may be OT for an answer, but it's a consideration.

Next:  When I wired my son's house we installed the new meter base which lead to a 200 amp generator transfer switch with an external main breaker. That technically made the main panel a sub-panel, so I floated the neutral from the ground. Passed inspection that way.

I don't know if an external breaker on the main/meter combo would force the inside panel to be treated as a sub-panel which would require 4 wire service to it.  **Thanks to @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact for the input**    If the main panel is behind a main breaker, it must be treated as a sub-panel.    That's not a big deal if its in the same structure, just 2 hots a neutral and a ground (4 wire) and make sure the grounds and neutrals are isolated (floated) so that the neutral only serves the neutral bus and the ground only services the grounding bus and they are not bonded (connected).

Comment: An external *breaker* would really be the "main panel", just a small one. Everything after, even if it is a 42-space 200A panel, is a sub.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   that's what I thought but wasn't positive and I don't want to give bad advice.  I'll update my answer based on your comment.   thanks!